# Samsung Galaxy Tablet does not allow entering floating point numbers to inputs with "number" type

Tags: android, html, android-browser, html-input, galaxy-tab

Our client wants us to display numeric keyboard for an input field so basically I created a field like:

`<input type="number" name="quantity" step=".01" value="0.00" />`

However, Galaxy Tablet erases "." and merges numbers before and after it, also disables "." in the keyboard.

Is there another way to solve this issue or display numeric keyboard in input field when using type="text"?

Note:
I tried using **pattern** attribute (which works on iPhone).
I tested this issue on various Android devices with Android 2.1+. I did not encounter this error on any other HTC and Samsung devices.

Comment: is by any chance your tablet set to european number format? - `decimal point` and `comma` are inversely used in european number format

Comment: unfortunately no, I am testing on US keyboard and also client tests in Australia.

Comment: Which Galaxy-tab and which version of android?

Comment: @PrashantGupta I'm having the issue on Galaxy Tab GT-P7510 (10 inch) on Android 3.2

Comment: It works on my Galaxy Tab 10.1 (PT-7510), although I was never graced with an update to 3.2. At least we can rule out it being an issue on Android 3.1.

Comment: Set property of your Edittext or text box from your layout xml file

Comment: @Yash This is not related to Android SDK or Android Layouts. This is about HTML5 input types in an Android browser or WebView.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is another way.

1. Way 1: don't use `type="number"` but use `type="text"`
2. Way 2: Apply way 1 for only Android phones. Detect User-Agent etc.
3. Way 3: Apply way 1 for only broken implementations. See: [What models of Samsung smartphones have missing period for html5 input type="number"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205511/what-models-of-samsung-smartphones-do-not-support-html5-input-type-number)
4. Way 4: Use `type="tel"'` for only Android or broken. (can't use on iPhone as no period then)
5. Way 5: use `type="text"` and then javascript with custom behavior. See:

Period always shows: http://jsbin.com/heqeduyi/1/

Period shows once 3 digits: http://jsbin.com/yinaweho/1

Comment: Would the following work? `<input inputmode="decimal" type="text" />`.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to use `type="tel"` instead of `type="number"`. Unfortunately on iOS `type="tel"` doesn't display the `,` char on the keyboard (at least I didn't find it there). You can check the user agent for iOS devices and then change `type` on `"number"`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting step to "any". Like:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" step="any" />
```

I took out the "value" because I think you should, even if just for testing

Answer (score 1):

I do this in C#/Xamarin and what works for me on the code side (I dynamically build up forms) is using the following:

```
   EditText edittext1 = new EditText(view.Context);
   edittext1.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score -1):

To have decimal point in the numeric keyboard on Android Samsung devices use this in you EditText:

```
 android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```