# HTML 5 input type "number" with step="any" => No decimal separator on Chrome Soft-Keyboard

Tags: android, google-chrome

I would like to have a HTML 5 Input Element like:

```
<input type="number" step="any" value="3.5"/>
```

This works fine on my iPhone Safari Browser but not on Chrome for Android.
It shows the right Soft-Keyboard, but not the decimal separator. So I'm not
able to enter any decimal places.

Are there e.g. any JavaScript tweaks that make the chrome browser show the
right keyboard?

Because it feels like a bug: Can someone point me to the Chrome for Android Issue Tracker to open up a case for this?

Comment: Had this issue too have you had any joy yet tried step="0.01" and that did not seem to work.

Comment: Same issue even on S4, I ended up installing Google keyboard it shows the decimal separator as expected. Hope Samsung or Chrome fixes this in the S5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same problem and came accross this link: [Google Chrome on Android (and only Android) Does not allow Decimal with type number and step="any"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514162/google-chrome-on-android-and-only-android-does-not-allow-decimal-with-type-num)

I have not yet tested on a iDevice, but i got the problem on my Samsung Galaxy SIII.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, but according to the W3 specification that other browsers does not follow.  The fix is supposed to be "any", but Chrome hasn't implemented that either.