# Ionic/HTML5 - Decimal Keyboard Input?

Tags: android, ios, html, ionic-framework

How do I display a numeric keyboard **with** a decimal button on iOS *and* Android? Is there an Ionic-specific way to do this?

I'm able to display a numeric keyboard on both iOS and Android with the following:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

iOS appears to disregard the `type` of value "number" and displays the number pad based off the `pattern` attribute, but the `type` is set to "number" anyway for Android.

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that I have tried `pattern="[0-9.]*"`. iOS simply shows the full keyboard when I do this.

**Edit2:** I've also tried `pattern="\d+[,.]?\d*"` - again, to no avail.

Comment: Try `pattern="[0-9.]*"`.

Comment: On Android there's no way to force a specific keyboard.  You give it an input type, and the keyboard (which is an app) decides the best thing to show for it.  If it decides not to show a ., there's no way to force it.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I forgot to mention I tried that to no avail. That was my first attempt after I found that the pattern of `[0-9]*` worked for a regular number pad.

Comment: @Chad Any progress with this at all?

Comment: @Cᴀʟʟᴏᴅᴀᴄɪᴛʏ nope, there does not seem to be a universal way to achieve this, at least not yet.

Answer (score 6):

Try the below syntax to achieve this. Its working in iPhone and Android.

`<ion-input inputmode="decimal" type="number" />`

Comment: After testing every conceivable techniques that i could find on internet, this is the only way i could have a decimal point on my iphone. I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: Works on Ionic as well.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the problem is relative to some samsung devices only.

I have the same issue that you describe on Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0 (android 4.4.2) but everything works fine on Nexus simply using

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

related posts [Google Chrome on Android (and only Android) Does not allow Decimal with type number and step="any"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514162/google-chrome-on-android-and-only-android-does-not-allow-decimal-with-type-num)

and [Samsung Galaxy Tablet does not allow entering floating point numbers to inputs with "number" type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134903/samsung-galaxy-tablet-does-not-allow-entering-floating-point-numbers-to-inputs-w/23389191#23389191)

Comment: This does not work on iOS. I'm starting to think it's (currently) not possible to show a numeric keyboard w/ decimal on both iOS **and** Android.

Answer (score 0):

refer this link:
https://github.com/skol-pro/ion-digit-keyboard-v2#6---example--demo

just hide the native keyboard on setfocus().